# How to put background image of an activity during runtime?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, background, imageview

In my app, I am letting the user to select a background image(from a gallery of images using Gallery), i.e., on clicking a button, lets say, 'theme', 3-4 images are shown, and the user gets to select one of the images.

Now as soon as he does that, the image should appear at the background of the activity..I am trying to save this choice, by the user, in my database..

but I really have no idea how to proceed, that is, when the 'theme' button is selected, a 'themepick' activity starts, and a gallery of 3-4 images appear...when the user selects an image, this themepick activity is 'finished' and we go back to the initial activity..now in this activity, I am letting the user enter some data(through text fields) . After the user clicks save, the data is going into the database, and is being retrieved well. But i also want to save the path to the selected image(from the themepick activity), to the database, and when I am retrieving all the data and displaying the data(in a separate activity, lets say), the image should come in the background as well.

I tried to  elaborate as much as possible. 
I urgently need a solution as my submission is due in 2 days. 
Thank you!

Comment: This is really nice, but what's your problem exactly? Which part of the story does not work? Be more specific.

Comment: You need to make your question more specific.

Comment: sure! What i need is: I want to display the image which the user had selected in the 'themepick' activity, to a separate activity, whose layout file is, lets say, diary.xml...now, this selected image should appear in the background in diary.xml...what i am not getting is: the android:background is mentioned beforehand, and has no id...so how will i be able to fire the image during run-time...or maybe, there is some work-around for this...like, for once, I thought of using an Image View...please suggest. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Answer (score 0):

You question doesn't seems to be specific on your problem . If I understood correctly your trying to set a background of an layout on runtime.

You need to find the layout Id and set background as below

```
View layout= findViewById( R.id.layout);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream); // your image file stream from a path
BitmapDrawable bg = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
layout.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
```

Let me know if it helps u.. :)